# How to prevent flip card overlapping navbar in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have used the W3Schools CSS for a flip card https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp for a website which I am building and, overall, it works perfectly.

However, the card back is positioned absolutely and this causes an unusual issue which I cannot figure out how to solve.

The navbar is sticky and all elements on the page go under it as the page is scrolled up with the exception of the flip card front image:
[image]

Notice how the hanburger menu is obscured by the front of the card, but not the back.

Ideally, I would like this not to happen. I know the issue is with the CSS

```
position: absolute;
```

but this is necessary for the card to stay as one object rotating on its own axis. A workaround would be to place the first picture not in a flip card but an ordinary picture element, but I would like to be able to have maybe 15 such cards on a gallery page but without this overlap.

If the issue isn't clear please ask for any clarifications.

The link above to W3Schools has all the CSS used, the HTML below is what is used for the page element in question, which is all based on CSS grid:

```
<div class="maincontent-news">
                    <h2>News</h2>
                    <p>
                    Grid Collective is pleased to be included in the <a href="https://mcauleyplace.ie/">McAuley Place Artist in the Lobby</a> for 2021. Although restrictions meant it could not take place as planned in early April, we hope that it will go ahead this year. In the meantime, we continue to work collaboratively on the given theme of Hope and Rebirth.
                    </p>
                    <br>
                    <p>
                    Many of the pictures on the site are <em>flip cards</em>, that is, if you hover the mouse over the pictureit will flip over to reveal further information on the back.
                    </p>
                    <br>
                    <br>
    
                    <div class="gridpicture">
                        <div class="picture">

                            <div class="flip-card">
                            
                              <div class="flip-card-inner">
                              
                                <div class="flip-card-front">
                                  <img src="images/light.png" alt="Grid Collective" style="width:18.75em;height:18.75em; alt="Where the light shines in">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="flip-card-back">
                                    <h3 class="bernard">Where the light shines in</h3>
                                    <p class="bernard">Bernard van Giessen</p>
                                    <p>Photography</p>
                                    <p>Exhibition: <i><a href="exhiboptions.html">So many options...</a></i></p>
                                </div>
                                
                              </div>
                              
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    
                    
                </div><!-- END maincontent-news-->
```

All the best,

Dermot

Comment: Have you tried z-index?

Comment: Hi Rob, yes I did but it made no difference, or I did not specify enough z-orders for different elements.
OMG - I went back and made on simple change - setting the header grid z-index = 2 and that made all the difference. I had been using z-index on the flip card and that was pointless, as it turns out!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rob's comment the problem has been solved. In my CSS I set the z-index of my grid header element to 2 and that made the issue go away.
I had tried z-index setting in the flip card CSS but to no avail but all i had to do was tells the header it was top dog and that worked!
Thanks to Rob Moll for suggesting the way forward.